# JS - Deleting unnecessary objects inside a list of objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object inside my Node server that contains thousands of objects, each object is a person and he has a totalScore.
it looks something like this:

```
var mainObject = { //it's unsorted, but no need to sort it anyway
    john: {totalScore: 5, info: "No"},
    james: {totalScore: 3, info: "No"},
    lee: {totalScore: 55, info: "No"}
}
```

Now, I want to remain with 1000 objects inside my mainObject, but the problem is I need to wipe the lowest scores with delete mainObject[name] before sending to the client(other solution other than delete is acceptable).

The indexes of each object inside the mainObject shouldn't be switched with one another(there is a reason), simply the lowest scores need to go and the list should be sent to the client as an object and be exactly at 1000 length.

Comment: You can't sort an object though...

Comment: I know, you can't sort it with Array.prototype.sort() but maybe there is a manipulation through looping or some other method to do what I want.

Comment: Define 'wipe'. Deleting the property won't leave you with 1000 objects. And Objects aren't lists and don't have a length.

Comment: Why not transform the object into array, with elements `{id: 'john', totalScore: 5}`, sorting that, getting all but 1000 top, and removing those from the original object?

Comment: canis minor, can you show what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to apply Array-based concepts like length and ordering to an Object. That simply won't do.

To achieve what you want, you're going to have to convert your Object to an Array. One way you could do that is like so:

```js
var mainObject = {
    john: {totalScore: 5, info: "No"},
    james: {totalScore: 3, info: "No"},
    lee: {totalScore: 55, info: "No"},
};

var mainArray = Object.keys(mainObject).map(function (name) {
  return Object.assign({}, mainObject[name], {name});
});

console.log(mainArray);
```

You can then sort your Array by score and return only the N highest entries:

```js
var mainArray = [
  {
    "totalScore": 5,
    "info": "No",
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "totalScore": 3,
    "info": "No",
    "name": "james"
  },
  {
    "totalScore": 55,
    "info": "No",
    "name": "lee"
  }
]

mainArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.totalScore - a.totalScore;
});

console.log(mainArray.slice(0, 1000));
```

If for some reason your client *absolutely needs* to get back an Object rather than an Array of Objects, you can always convert back:

```js
var mainArray = [
  {
    "totalScore": 5,
    "info": "No",
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "totalScore": 3,
    "info": "No",
    "name": "james"
  },
  {
    "totalScore": 55,
    "info": "No",
    "name": "lee"
  }
];

var mainObject = mainArray.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
  var name = curr.name;
  delete curr.name;
  prev[name] = curr;
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(mainObject);
```

But at this point you've done a fairly absurd amount of work to achieve your goal. Enough work that it implies this is actually [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), and you should reconsider the decisions that have led you to this point.

Comment: Your function sorts indexes from lowest to highest, and I need only the lowest scores to be wiped out without sorting the valid scores...

Comment: then you can juste replace

mainArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.totalScore - a.totalScore;
});

with 

mainArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.totalScore - b.totalScore;
});

Comment: @RunningFromShia How exactly do you expect to be able to identify which scores are the lowest scores without sorting them?

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash

```
var desiredAmountOfObjects = 2

var mainObject = { //it's unsorted, but no need to sort it anyway
    john: {totalScore: 5, info: "No"},
    james: {totalScore: 3, info: "No"},
    lee: {totalScore: 55, info: "No"}
}

var mainArray = _.map(mainObject, (value, key) => Object.assign(value, { key }))

mainArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.totalScore - a.totalScore;
});

var choppingBlock = mainArray.slice(desiredAmountOfObjects).map(chop => chop.key)

console.log(choppingBlock);

var desiredObject = _.omitBy(mainObject, (value, key) => choppingBlock.indexOf(key) > -1)

console.log(desiredObject)
```

http://jsbin.com/gijuduzole/1/edit?js,console

Set desiredAmountOfObject to 1000 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object with lowest scores removed using
Object.keys and Array iteration methods:

```js
const mainObject = {
    john: {totalScore: 5, info: "No"},
    james: {totalScore: 3, info: "No"},
    lee: {totalScore: 55, info: "No"}
};

const keys = Object.keys(mainObject);

const lowest = keys.map(key => mainObject[key].totalScore).sort()[0];

const removed = keys.reduce((result, key) => {
    if(mainObject[key].totalScore > lowest){
        result[key] = mainObject[key];
    }
    return result;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log('without objects with lowest score');
console.log(removed);

// EDIT -- Or, to retain keys:

const removed2 = keys.reduce((result, key) => {
    result[key] = mainObject[key].totalScore > lowest
        ? mainObject[key]
        : undefined;
    return result;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log('retaining all keys');
console.log(removed2);
```

*References*
[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: How do you plan to delete properties but still be left with 1000? That doesn't make any sense. You seem to be missing key context from your question if that's the case.

Comment: because on the server there are thousands of objects in mainObject, my 3 objects were just an example

Comment: Deleting a property, like you said in the question, will remove it, leaving you with fewer properties. See edit for retaining all keys.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment - from initial object create an array that you **can** sort, then take all but x results, and remove those results from the initial object.

```
// object
var mainObject = { //it's unsorted, but no need to sort it anyway
        john: {totalScore: 5, info: "No"},
        james: {totalScore: 3, info: "No"},
        lee: {totalScore: 55, info: "No"}
    }

// array
var array = [];
for (var i in mainObject)
array.push({ key: i, score: mainObject[i].totalScore });

// sort
array.sort(function(a,b){ return a.score < b.score });

// keep top x
var remove = array.slice(2);

// delete all the others
for (var i=0; i<remove.length; i++)
delete mainObject[remove[i].key];

console.log(mainObject);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrc8hpya/1/

Answer (score -2):

There are plenty of libraries that can help you with this kind of problems (underscore, lodash, ramda).
An example using ramda:

```
const mainObject = { //it's unsorted, but no need to sort it anyway
    john: {totalScore: 5, info: "No"},
    james: {totalScore: 3, info: "No"},
    lee: {totalScore: 55, info: "No"}
}

const obj = R.filter((person) => person.totalScore > 50, mainObject);
```

This way you don't have to worry about convert to array, just apply the filter and you will get the objects.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Your code filters for people having score greater than 50 -- not what he wants. Hypothetically, if the list of people had only scores greater than 50... then the filter does nothing.